# How to get message causing restart in Akka Persistence

Tags: scala, akka, akka-persistence

I'm having `PersistenceActor` and I'd like to do something in it's `preRestart` method, basing on a message, which caused the restart. For regular actor that would be easy, as there is message passed to `preRestart` method:

```
def preRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any])
```

However for `PersistentActor` that can't be done in that way, because each time `None` is passed as a message attribute. It is caused by that piece of code in `Eventsourced.scala`:

```
override protected[akka] def aroundPreRestart(reason: Throwable, message: Option[Any]): Unit = {
try {
  internalStash.unstashAll()
  unstashAll(unstashFilterPredicate)
} finally {
  message match {
    case Some(WriteMessageSuccess(m, _)) ⇒
      flushJournalBatch()
      super.aroundPreRestart(reason, Some(m))
    case Some(LoopMessageSuccess(m, _)) ⇒
      flushJournalBatch()
      super.aroundPreRestart(reason, Some(m))
    case Some(ReplayedMessage(m)) ⇒
      flushJournalBatch()
      super.aroundPreRestart(reason, Some(m))
    case mo ⇒
      flushJournalBatch()
      super.aroundPreRestart(reason, None)
  }
}
}
```

Does anyone know why `None` is passed there, losing the original message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to be an oversight and something we should fix in Akka, I have opened a ticket to track fixing it: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues/21824